# how to use service like AsyncTask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I want to use service that can be like  AsyncTask.
on the back ground its opens stream and on hold just showing process bar.
when it will finished its just will have the parameter of stream that did on the background.
if you can give me a simple code to don this.

my async task looks like that:

```
  protected void onPreExecute() {
      Dialog.setMessage("Doing something...");
      Dialog.show();          
  }
```

and my service supposed to do this:

```
  try{

     URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

     // Read all the text returned by the server
     BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
                                 (new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
     String str;
     while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // str is one line of text;
         readLine() 
         strips the newline  character(s)
     }
     //all is ok
     in.close();
```

now how can I implement  those things to service.
I know that I have a lot of examples but they arent simple just If you can post simple code that do this it will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah here is the sample code:

```
public void draw(int tot) throws IOException, URISyntaxException{

    total--;
    sv = new ScrollView(this);
    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.opsbuds);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    sv.addView(ll);

//  TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
    //tv1.setText("Question: "+question);
//  tv1.setTextColor(Color.rgb(80, 00, 80));
//  ll.addView(tv1);
    img=new ImageView(this);
    //Bitmap drawable = getBitmapFromURL("http://bufferedsoftware.com/survey/db/php/authentication/upload/" + option1[tot]);

    new DownloadFileFromURL().execute(); 

    Button btn=new Button(this);
    btn.setLayoutParams (new LayoutParams 
            (LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp1.setMargins(20, 10, 0, 0);
    btn.setText("Question");
    btn.setTextSize(20);
    btn.setWidth(100);
    btn.setHeight(40);
    btn.setLayoutParams(lp1);
    btn.setTextColor(Color.rgb(80, 00, 80));
    btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button);
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    img.setLayoutParams(lp1);
    ll.addView(img);
    ll.addView(btn);
    this.setContentView(sv);
    temp++;
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case progress_bar_type:
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Image. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setMax(100);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
        return pDialog;
    default:
        return null;
    }
}

class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

     Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        showDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {  

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "format2"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("surveyId", surveyId));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quesNo", Integer.toString(ques_no)));
        //http post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(surveyURL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
        }
        //convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");

            String line="0";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }


        try{
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            JSONObject json_data=null;
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
            quest_id=json_data.getString("question_id");
            question=json_data.getString("question");
            options=json_data.getString("op");
            option1=json_data.getString("image_name");
            quesNo=json_data.getString("question_no");
            help=json_data.getString("Help");
            mandatory=json_data.getString("mandatory");
            others=json_data.getString("others");
            condition=json_data.getString("condition1");
            total++;    
        }
        catch(JSONException e1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Data Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (ParseException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }  

         try {
               URL url = new URL("http://182.71.220.141/survey/db/php/authentication/upload/" + option1);
               HttpGet httpRequest = null;

               httpRequest = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);

               HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
               BufferedHttpEntity b_entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
               InputStream input = b_entity.getContent();

              bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("log", "bad url");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("log", "io error");
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        dismissDialog(progress_bar_type);
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but this not a service I need a service to do the connection